# manual constraints of auto layout conflict with constraint defined on XIB

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, xcode4.3, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am learning about auto layout and giving the layout using constraint manually on lable and button.

Now if I create two controls dynamically and add as a subview to my main view and give constraint to it .
 It is working fine but if I put that control on xib and give IBOutlet to them and then give constraint to it by code.
 It is not displaying both label and button in proper way.
 My understanding is When we put control on xib (my autolayout feature is on) It has already defined some constraint to it and when we give constraint by code it is conflict with xib constraint.

So can I give constraint by code to controls that is defined in XIB and if not what is the way to define manual constraint to control that is already defined in XIB 
Should I create them dynamically only or Is there any way to meet my criteria?

Comment: Are you working with Xcode 4 or 5?

Comment: I am using xcode 4 @ArkadiuszHolko

Comment: Thanks. Have you watched Auto Layout sessions from WWDC 2012 (there's 3 of them)?

Comment: ok i will see that. are you suggesting that I found the answer from that right

Comment: It's hard to understand Auto Layout without watching them, because its description in the documentation is lousy. If something is still unclear after watching them, please ask.

Comment: appreciate this @ArkadiuszHolko.. thanks for your comments.

Comment: you are right @ArkadiuszHolko. I got my answer. Autoresize is the subset of nsconstraint so you have to use either nsconstraint or autorisizing  .